# MySQL Ordering by index id from separate table

Tags: php, mysql

I have run into a problem that I'm sure is easy to achieve. I have a table for some merchandise. It holds all the information including the id for the manufacturer. The information about the manufacturer is in a separate table. When users are searching they have filter options. The one I'm having trouble with is filtering by manufacturer.

```
Products Table: cs_products
id | name    | manufacturer_id
---------------------------
1  | mic     | 3
2  | cable   | 2
3  | speaker | 1

Manufacturer Table: cs_manufacturer
id | name
------------------
1  | JBL
2  | Rapco
3  | Shure
```

When the query is ran I need to ORDER BY cs_manufacturer.name:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cs_products ORDER BY cs_manufacturer.name")
```

What is the proper syntax for this?

Comment: Google `MySQL Join`. Also notice that the `mysql_` extension is deprecated in PHP 5.5. Move to newer extensions like `mysqli_` or `PDO`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM cs_products JOIN cs_manufacturer
ON cs_product.manufacturer_id = cs_manufacturer.id
ORDER BY cs_manufacturer.name
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing your join.

```
SELECT * FROM cs_products 
JOIN cs_manufacturer on cs_products.manufacturer_id = cs_manufacturer.id 
ORDER BY cs_manufacturer.name
```