# MySQL ORDER BY Another table's column names

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have one table with items for an order that looks like this:

```
Product | Color | Size | Size Range ID (from a different, joined table)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Shirt   | Blue  |  L   |   1
Shirt   | Blue  |  M   |   1
Shirt   | Blue  |  S   |   1
```

Note that the sizes are sorted in alphabetical order in the table above.

I also have a size ranges table that looks like this:

```
id | size_01 | size_02 | size_03
--------------------------------
 1 |    S    |   M     |   L
```

How can I force the items on the first table to ORDER BY the position of the size in the second table?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Ordering by index id from separate table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539237/mysql-ordering-by-index-id-from-separate-table)

Comment: You could simply `ORDER BY Size DESC`, but that may not be generic enough if you add new sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `join` to combine the tables and then `field()` to get the position in the column list:

```
select i.*
from items i left outer join
     SizeRange sr
     on i.SizeRangeId = sr.SizeRangeId
order by field(i.Size, sr.size_01, sr.size_02, sr.size_03)
```

Comment: Also, to get the sizes from the size_range column we will be using something like:  

    SELECT c.column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c WHERE c.table_name = 'size_ranges' AND c.column_name != 'id' AND c.column_name != 'name' ORDER BY c.column_name 

that way the number of sizes can be changed on the fly

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  MAX(CASE Size WHEN 'S' THEN Size ELSE '' END) AS 'size_01',
  MAX(CASE Size WHEN 'L' THEN Size ELSE '' END) AS 'size_02',
  MAX(CASE Size WHEN 'M' THEN Size ELSE '' END) AS 'size_03'
FROM Test
GROUP BY Product
```